# 2depth value in path : Angular2 RouterConfig

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

RouterConfig's path only accept 1depth value?

I mean... is this not allowed?

```
{ path: 'service/band',}
```

#### with this configuration, It fails to route.

```
export const appRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: 'service/band',  
        component: EventDashboard
    }
]
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER = provideRouter(appRoutes);
```

http://localhost/service/band <-- not work!
access fails.
[image]

```
VM73168:77 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'band'
    at resolvePromise (eval at 989 (polyfills.js:284), <anonymous>:538:32)
```

#### But with this configuration, It succeed to route.

```
export const appRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: 'serviceband',  
        component: EventDashboard
    }
]
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER = provideRouter(appRoutes);
```

http://localhost/serviceband <-- work!

#### versions

angular2 rc3, 
angular2 Route-3.0.0.alpha8 using.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit more complicated than your example, but starting from the plunker for the router example from the docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html I simply modified the "/heroes" route in app/heroes/hereoes.routes to be "/show/heroes" and modified the related routerLink in app/app.component.

```
export const HeroesRoutes: RouterConfig = [
   { path: 'show/heroes',  component: HeroListComponent },
   { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];
```

And then

```
<a [routerLink]="['/show/heroes']">Heroes</a>
```

If you take a look at the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/zzwJsKiYFD3VhjC3IdW7?p=preview you'll see that clicking the heroes link works just fine.

Can you post any more of your code to help determine what your specific issue is?

EDIT: This may just be a simple case of your app not being rebuilt when you change the route. I've run into that a few times with webpack...

Comment: Thanks @John Ackerman. Could you please give some information related with webpack you've met? Actually I am upgrading Router 2 --> 3 and My application is quite large and not easy to upload to plunker.  I am using webpack too.

Comment: Basically, for anything Angular2/Webpack related I've found this project on github (https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) to be very helpful. I've noticed in some of the more recent versions that the server refresh doesn't always work and I have to manually kick it when making route changes.